# can 'Program and Features' uninstall to call External UI?

Tags: wixsharp

Is it possible to get the uninstall request from 'program and features' to call the External UI?

I want to add some uninstall options. At the moment, a basic prompt appears and the pre uninstall actions file, but it is possible to return to the External UI?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're trying to do. I do know that when you're running an MSI with a UI the InstallUISequence will happen first, then the InstallExecuteSequence (between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize) is where the magic happens.

Comment: i am using WixSharp, it generates the WIX project. I have a WPF app that calls the MSI, but on uninstall, it is just going through basic UI confirming you want to uninstall. I want to ask the user if they want to remove their settings.
I could look into adding to the generated WIX project, but i would rather receive the uninstall action in the WPF app so the UI is consistent.

Comment: I would put an action in your WPF app that asks the user if they want to save their settings and then have the app do it. The problem with doing this in the actual uninstall is that the MSI and code for uninstalling is already on the user's system.

There is the possibility of editing the cached MSI before launching the uninstall but that's not supported and is probably over kill for what you're trying to do.